# Google Combo Chart veritcal axis with percentage sign and right axis without percentage sign

Tags: charts, google-spreadsheets

I want to create Google Stacking (100%) Combo Chart with a veritcal axis with percentage sign and right axis without percentage sign for a line serie.

The nearest I have come is to set scale factor to 100, what I want is scale 0-20 without the percentage sign for a right axes for the line serie

[image: My chart]